# Pointer to a class method in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

A have a lot of B classes, a class A has one object b. This object b has a function (calc) that needs a pointer to a method in an object of A. This method (fun) acess private variables in class (in my example just return 3).

```
class A;

class B {
public:
  virtual int calc ( int (A::*fun)())  {    return 2*fun();  };
};

class A {
  B* b;

public:
  A (B* b_) : b (b_) {};
  int fun() { return 3; };
  int run(){ return b->calc(&A::fun); };
};

int main() {
  B* b = new B();
  A a(b);
  a.run();
  return 0;
}
```

How can I use a pointer to a method correctly in definition of `calc` method in class B?

I am getting this error message:

```
teste.cpp:10:58: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member     function in ‘fun (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* fun) (...)’
   virtual int calc ( int (A::*fun)())  {    return 2*fun();  };
                                                      ^
```

Comment: Pointers to non-static member functions are indeed fun, but you don't work with them like that.  I'd look into std::function

Comment: Why is a C answer being linked as a duplicate for a C++ question? Calling member functions is not the same as calling functions in C.

Comment: I believe that this is a better duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/passing-a-member-function-as-an-argument-in-c

Comment: That is a very strange duplicate for this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the `std::function` approach if it's feasible for you. However, for the sake of completeness, here's how you would correctly use pointer-to-member functions.

The pointer-to-member itself doesn't store the "current" instance of `A`, so you need to pass that explicitly. Then you use the special `->*` (or `.*`) syntax to call it.

```
virtual int calc (A* value, int (A::*fun)())  {
  return 2 * (value->*fun)();
};
```

Then you would call it as `b->calc(this, &A::fun);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it your way, but the member function must be [called](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) on a particular instance:

```
class A;

class B {
public:
    virtual int calc(A* a, int (A::*fun)()) { return 2 * (a->*fun)(); };
};

class A {
    B* b;

public:
    A(B* b_) : b(b_) {};
    int fun() { return 3; };
    int run() { return b->calc(this, &A::fun); }; // now also passing this pointer
};

int main() {
    B* b = new B();
    A a(b);
    a.run();
    return 0;
}
```

If you can live without `calc()` being virtual then a lambda is also an option:

```
class A;

class B {
public:
    template<typename T>
    int calc(T fun) { return 2 * fun(); };
};

class A {
    B* b;

public:
    A(B* b_) : b(b_) {};
    int fun() { return 3; };
    int run() {
        return b->calc([this]() {return fun(); } );
    };
};

int main() {
    B* b = new B();
    A a(b);
    a.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use C++11, then you should use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind): Otherwise you need to use a [pointer to member function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) + a pointer to the instance.

**With C++11**

```
#include <functional>

class B {
public:
  virtual int calc (std::function<int()>&& fun) { return 2 * fun();  }; };
};

class A {
  B* b;

public:
  A (B* b_) : b (b_) {};
  int fun() { return 3; };
  int run() { return b->calc(std::bind(&A::fun, this)); };
};
```

**Without C++11**

```
class B {
public:
  virtual int calc (int(A::*fnptr)(), A* a) { return 2 * (a->*fnptr)(); };
};

class A {
  B* b;

public:
  A (B* b_) : b (b_) {};
  int fun() { return 3; };
  int run() { return b->calc(&A::fun, this); };
};
```

See example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0028ebe24c7d0d0).

Answer (score 0):

A pointer-to-class method is defined and initialized as (assuming SomeFn matches the signature):

```
RetType (ClassName::*pfn)(Args) = &ClassName::SomeFn;
```

And is called as:

```
ClassName * ptr = GetClassPtr();
(ptr->*pfn)(arg, arg);
```